# What does access from VirtualBox to the host depend on?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I (unfortunately) have a Windows XP instance running in VirtualBox on my Mac, which is running a dev server (Node.js connect).

I'm successfully able to access the dev server from the VM's browser (which is, tragically, IE8), using the host's ip address, BUT only when my WiFi is connected to one of the two networks I've tried this on.

I.e., when I'm connected to an Airport Express router, it works fine. But it doesn't work when I'm connected to the router at home (sorry, I can't recall the router's make ATM; it's a cable modem supplied by Optimum).

So, am I correct in thinking that the router is playing a role in whether or not access is possible? And, what would I need to do to make it work?

Happy to supply more info if needed.

TIA

P.S. I'm pretty sure this was the right forum to ask this Q – rather than StackO' – but if I'm wrong, please don't be hatin'.

Comment: This is *not* the proper site for this question, see the [FAQ]. It might fit on [SU], but check their FAQ and archive first.

Comment: @SvenW Seriously I don't understand why it's not the right site. FAQ mentions "network routing" and "virtualization". I know this is not a production server, but it IS a dev server, and I AM developing in a professional capacity. I just happen to have holes in my understanding of networking, and I'm looking to learn about it.

Comment: Why did you have to bring operating system religion and browser wars into this? There's enough hate in the world already without adding all this.

Comment: @meetamit dev setups are off topic. If you're not a sysadmin, chances are your question it off topic here. Dev tools are on topic on SO though.

Comment: from the [FAQ]: **and ist not about ... Anything in a home setting**. Dev systems are off-topic as well.  Also, I will never understand why people want to argue about topicality if they are even pointed to a better place to ask the question.

Comment: @gecko Fair enough, the browser/OS sentiment wasn't necessary. Was actually just venting about still having to deal with obsolete tech (which is what both of those are). Thanks anyway for answering my Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

> Bridged networking
>
> This is for more advanced networking needs such as network simulations and running servers in a guest. When enabled, VirtualBox connects to one of your installed network cards and exchanges network packets directly, circumventing your host operating system's network stack.
>
> On Macintosh hosts, functionality is limited when using AirPort (the Mac's wireless networking) for bridged networking. Currently, VirtualBox supports only IPv4 over AirPort. For other protocols such as IPv6 and IPX, you must choose a wired interface.

I assume you have read the man pages for virtualbox? Let us know what you've tried, as it helps.